# Symfony 3 custom user provider using Bcrypt

Tags: php, symfony, bcrypt, symfony-security, symfony-3.1

In reading https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-class/, all of the examples that I've seen implement the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` for the `User` class. This interface defines a method for a salt field - but I'm wanting to use Bcrypt for the hashing algorithm.

In my `app/config/security.yml` file I have:

```
encoders:
    AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```

The linked document says:

> If getSalt() returns nothing, then the submitted password is simply encoded using the algorithm you specify in security.yml. If a salt is specified, then the following value is created and then hashed ...

Does this imply that if I specify for Bcrypt to be used, then I don't need a salt field in the users DB table (since the salt is in the same string as the rest of the password when hashed with Bcrypt)?

If that is the case then I'm guessing that I could just leave the `getSalt()` method with an empty body so that no salt would be specified and the algorithm in security.yml would be used.

Are my above assumptions correct? If they are not, how can I implement a user provider with bcrypt being used to hash passwords?

I'm using Symfony 3.1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Creating your First User](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#creating-your-first-user):

> Do you need to use a Salt property?
>
> If you use bcrypt, no. Otherwise, yes. All passwords must be hashed
>   with a salt, but bcrypt does this internally. Since this tutorial does
>   use bcrypt, the `getSalt()` method in User can just `return null` (it's
>   not used). If you use a different algorithm, you'll need to uncomment
>   the salt lines in the User entity and add a persisted salt property.

if you want to use Bcrypt just `return null` in the `getSalt()` method.

Comment: This really helped me. I'm creating a custom UserProvider and have defined my own User class since I'm using a database that Doctrine doesn't support. Both seemed to expect I have a salt separate from my hashed password.